# What method to test percentage against population percentage?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have population of 6 regions, and also customers from these regions. 
What is the best way to test if the percentages of customers from these regions are about the same as the population percentages? Can I do Chi-square in this case?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to test if a sample proportion (a statistic) is different from a population proportion (a parameter)?

Comment: Yes. I want to see if the proportion in my sample different from population proportion or not.  I finally used testing one proportion by Z-test.

Comment: I suppose a chi-square test could be used for the corresponding frequencies, but the results would not be helpful.